# Is there any plugin for calendar and time(clock) in jQuery?

Tags: datetime, plugins, jquery-plugins, time, calendar

I am looking for a jQuery plug-in for calendar and watch also is there any plug in available for these in jQuery?

Plug-in need not to be only jQuery but if it is jQuery plug-in I prefer it more.

Comment: Here there are 30 of them : http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-calendar-plugins/ for you to chose.

Comment: @Jhurtado i need even watch plug in is there any plugin for watch also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about [this one for time picker?](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/time-picker)

and [this one for the date?](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: ,now nothing is there on the link for time picker